# 'In so far as' and 'As far as' --Are the two conjunctions synonyms?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, conjunctions

'In so far as' and 'As far as'   -- Are the two conjunctions synonyms?  I was searching in Net, but I could not find the answer. They seem to be similar in meaning. Can anyone please explain, with an example, if they are different?

Answer (score 1):

They are not conjunctions, but idiomatic compound prepositions, and they have different meanings:

> [1] ***As far as*** the weather was concerned, we were very lucky.
>
> [2] ***As far as*** I know, he's still in Paris.
>
> [3] ***Insofar as*** it's any business of mine I'd say they should give up.

"As far as" in [1] means "regarding", and in [2] it means "to the best of my knowledge".

"Insofar as" in [3] means "to the extent that".

Comment: Why does contemporary grammar not treat the second **as** as a clause subordinator?  "as far *as* I know".  Would "to the extent that" be considered an idiomatic compound preposition?

Answer (score -1):

I think the key difference is in connotation.  Insofar implies inadequacy:

`Insofar as it matters, I think it's a bad idea [but it's not my decision]`.

whereas "as far as" can imply importance:

```
As far as I'm concerned, I think it's a bad idea [so it isn't going to happen].
```

Both mean "to the extent," but each points the addressee's mind in a different direction, or, as I like to say, invokes a different template in the hearer's mind in preparation for what follows.

Of the two, "as far as" fills the neutral space where there is no connotation.  Thus, we say "as far as I know" to mean "to the best of my knowledge, which may or may not be accurate" or "as far as the weather was concerned" to mean "I don't know how much you care about the weather, but to the extent that you do care about it...)  In common parlance, the latter use certainly boils down to "regarding...," but that raises the question of why "regarding" or "as to" wasn't used.

Comment: I think the putative connotation of "inadequacy" is not really present.  Both phrases refer to a limit or extent. *Plaintiff's petition is granted insofar as it asks for injunctive relief but not insofar as it seeks punitive damages.*

Comment: @TRomano I believe the negative connotation is present in your example.  Plaintiff clearly asked for more, and he got less than he asked. The connotation is not literally applied to a word in the sentence but to the good news/bad news from the speaker's point of view.  (Plaintiff may in fact be thrilled with this judgment, but the judge only knows that he is giving less than was asked.)  There is usually a "less-than"-ness in the usage, at least in my experience. I think BillJ's [3] is prototypical.

Comment: It's neutral and can go either way. "As a result, nearly everyone is both helped and harmed. For example, physicians and other health care professionals— *insofar as they are the beneficiaries of a mammoth medical-industrial complex* — are helped; at the same time— *insofar as they become the employees, slaves, or even scapegoats of the system* —they are also harmed."   from **Insanity: The Idea and Its Consequences** by Thomas Stephen Szasz, 1987.

Comment: @TRomano I disagree.  I don't like Dr. Szasz's usage. I would have preferred "to the extent that" for the first use (if the meaning in not better served by the more binary "inasmuch as" or even just "as beneficiaries of..." But I'll go so far as to say it's a matter of style. My default position is that different words exist to carry different semantic or even semiotic payloads. My spidey-sense detects a predominant tone of insufficiency rather than neutrality in "insofar as."  But maybe it's just confirmation bias.

Comment: It is used so frequently in a neutral manner that your detection of a negative, or preference that it be used with a negative, seems somewhat arbitrary: "They are true insofar as they are chosen rationally, but false insofar as they result from a flight from self-consciousness, rationalization, and moral renunciation." *Lonergan in the World: Self-Appropriation, Otherness, and Justice* by James Marsh. Toronto, 2014.

Comment: And yet, @BillJ went right where I would expect.  I can't really account for other writers' lack of commitment to nuance. But, as I said, you may be right. A writer should have a reason to choose one word over another, and some of my reasons may turn out to be idioglossia. I wonder what BillJ thinks.